# Kleopatra importing private key

Tags: windows, gpg4win, kleopatra

I'm using Kleopatra Version 3.1.4-gpg4win-3.1.5. I try to import private key (my private key is in a separate file, just a plain text) with GUI and I've got it imported without any problems.

However, when I want to decrypt some file, there is a popup that asks me for a passphrase. Since I have no passphrase, I leave it empty but this not work.

Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what (I've searched the Internet for some tips, but without any luck ;/)

Comment: Hmm I understand that my question can be stupid, nooby or something, but I would really benefit for the future, that if someone downvote, to leave info why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a way to do this in Kleopatra, but a workaround is to use  [PGP Anywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgp-anywhere/cdlcdnmhcodhagbmljapgbjdimjckilb) extension in Chrome - it doesn't need passphrase and works properly.